# Should I always pass aligned datatypes as pointers?

Tags: call, opencl, memory-alignment

I noticed that calling the `printf` function (with `cl_intel_printf` extension), the same variable of type `double` (8-byte aligned) printed multiple times gives different values; one of them is correct, the other one bogus (reading 4 bytes off). Does it mean that, as in c/c++, aligned datatypes should not be passed by value, but only by pointers (or by reference in `c++`)?

(More generally, what is the function caling convention for OpenCL? I read somewhere that all function calls are inlined, but `OpenCL in Action` speaks otherwise. Is that implementation-defined?)

Comment: (commenting because I can't offer an answer atm..) I think printf may be having trouble with doubles in general. Have you seen similar behaviour with floats or any int/int64 types? float64 is usually available as an extension, so my guess is that the printf you are using may have a bug regarding doubles. It is odd that the same 8-byte aligned value would print inconsistently. The extension 'cl_khr_byte_addressable_store' also comes to mind, but that has to do with non-aligned int values.

Comment: Thanks, @vocaro, I was in the end unable to reproduce it. Explanation in the anwer. Calling convention still not known to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by specifying `%g` instead of `%lg` for the double arguments to printf. With `%g`, some values were not printed correctly. (The compiler does not seem to have printf-syntax checker.)